# Convex ratio of two Gamma functions

Tags: calculus, transcendental-functions

Is the function $\Gamma(x+1)^2/\Gamma(x+1/2)^2$ convex on $[0,+\infty[$ ?

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a "do my challenge" site. If you don't explain why this problem might be of general interest, where it comes from, and what you tried to solve it, it will most likely just be closed, soon.

Comment: If it is, it is just barely so, since (from Watson's lemma, for example) that ratio is asymptotic to a constant multiple of the function $f(x)=x$.